# what if I have the same answer for more than one question?

Tags: discussion, answers

So I'd like to make sure that the people who land on "[What is the optimal age to neuter a male dog?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/134/884)" also get the answer I put on "[How does one determine when a female dog is appropriate to be spayed?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/2349/884)". The two questions are not duplicates... but my answer really applies to both. Do I just duplicate the answer or is there a slick way of making that answer show on both?

Answer (score 9):

Short of posting your answer in both places, there is no better way to do it if the information does indeed apply to both. However, don't just copy and paste. Please tailor your answers as much as possible to each specific question.